# ngAnimate throwing an error at line 992

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

I'm currently trying to figure out who broke my script, me or angular-animate.js. I'm pretty sure it's me, but hey, miracles could happen and I can be innocent this time.

This is my HTML code:

```
<body data-ng-app="app">

    <divdata-ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="checked"> Click me
        </label>
        <div data-ng-show="checked">
            Bu! 
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-animate.1.2.26.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/exercise-7.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is my exercise-7.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.checked = false;
}]);
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

[image]

The funny thing is that I'm not using "angular-animate.js", but "angular-animate.min.js". I do have the map file localy as well, but it points to the minified version. So it couldn't be because that, right?

In my Chrome console, I opened the error message and the file seems to be empty (even thought it doesn't exists).

[image]

So I downloaded the unminified version of angular-animate and I could finally see that it's complaining about row 992:

[image]

I can't understand this problem and I am reaching out to you guys. What did I do wrong? I can see that the angular-animate.js was changed approx 21 hours ago, but I am not sure if that is something relevant to my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You upgraded angular to 1.3.0 but left angular-animate on 1.2.26. Upgrade angular-animate to 1.3 and you'll be set:

- https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular-animate.js
- https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular-animate.min.js

Comment: Such a rookie mistake. Thanks!